# PHP save XML to file

Tags: php, xml, iis

I want to save XML files from a PHP script (original XML file and also create new XML file from old file) on a Windows Vista/7 with IIS 7 pc.

From this question, [How to save an XML file on the web server using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351652/how-to-save-an-xml-file-on-the-web-server-using-php), I found out that to save an existing file I needed to make that file writable by anyone.  That question talks about suexec to give permission to PHP to write files.  What is the equivalent in Windows/IIS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to set up the permissions yourself. Have a look at this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx for how to do it.

Comment: I have set the permissions on the existing file. My question was how to set PHP to be able to write new files to the web server.

Comment: You have to set the permissions on the folder that will contain the generated files

Comment: Isn't it a security problem to have write permission for anyone on the web server folder that contains the generated files?

Comment: Well, you just normally need the web user to have write access. Anyway, that's the way to go...