# Save and Display a XML file created by transforming values of another XML using Xsl file.

Tags: php, xml, xslt

Hi I have a xml file and i'm transforming it's values from xsl file in php. I want to display the new values as an xml. I can get values echoed in the php but when I put the header it gives an error saying junk after element. and I cannot use saveXML() to the returned string.
I need to save these returned information in a new xml file which I have no idea how to do. Please help me in this> thank you in advance.

php file

```
<?php
//header('Content-Type: text/xml');
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$xmlDoc->formatOutput = true;
$xmlDoc->load("rental.xml");
$xslDoc = new DomDocument('1.0');
$xslDoc->load("apartment.xsl");
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xslDoc);
$strXml= $proc->transformToXML($xmlDoc);
//echo (toXml($strXml));
echo ($strXml);
//echo $strXml->saveXML();
?>
```

xsl file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output  method="xml" indent="yes" />   
  <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="//property">
      <xsl:element name="rentalProperties">
        <xsl:element name="description">
        <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>  
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Not sure if that's the issue, but your xsl will not output valid xml if there is more than one property because it will not generate a root element. It seems like `rentalProperties` should be your root element, instead you will produce multiple `rentalProperties` elements for each property in your source.

Comment: Yes Now out put is coming as a xml. Thank you very much. Now i'll have to find how to save this as a xml file.

Comment: Tobias Klevenz do you know how to save it as a xml file

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351652/how-to-save-an-xml-file-on-the-web-server-using-php

Comment: it still gives the error call to function on non object

Comment: Tobias Klevenz it's working now thank you very much for your help. following is what i added $strXml= $proc->transformToXML($xmlDoc);
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0'); 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
$dom->formatOutput = true; 
$dom->loadXML($strXml);
echo $dom->saveXML();
$dom->save("../../data/test.xml");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will help u to save xml string to a file.

```
<?php
//header('Content-Type: text/xml');
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$xmlDoc->formatOutput = true;
$xmlDoc->load("rental.xml");
$xslDoc = new DomDocument('1.0');
$xslDoc->load("apartment.xsl");
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xslDoc);
$strXml= $proc->transformToXML($xmlDoc);
//echo (toXml($strXml));
echo ($proc->transformToXML($xmlDoc));
//$strXml->saveXML();

// Way to parse XML string and save to a file
$convertedXML = simplexml_load_string($strXml);
$convertedXML->saveXML("member.xml");
?>
```

Cheers.

Comment: You can refer the following link for the documentation of SimpleXML functions, which might come in handy. http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.simplexml.php